# Accesing from Swift to User Preferences

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to access to System and User Settings from Swift, but I have no idea if there is an API that allows to do that.

For example for Settings -> Cellular -> Current Period data, disk usage, and so on.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I think we'd all like that, but there's no official way to do it. This would make a good enhancement request to Apple.

Comment: thank you matt, I was just trying to confirm that was not "officially" possible.

Comment: As of iOS8 you can open your own apps settings with the [UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString key from UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Settings_Launch_URL) - but you can't open arbitrary settings locations. This **is** an officially supported way to get to your own app settings.